# How long can domestic rabbits live in wild

Tags: rabbits, containment

I lost my place to live and found myself in my car with my kids and two rabbits. My significant other and her mom moved in with her grandparents, who wouldn't take them. I called every animal rescue shelter within 100 miles to get rid of these rabbits because no one I knew had enough room for them nor wanted to take them; I was basically told they couldn't or wouldn't help.

**What do I do with them?**

They are both in one cage to save space in my car and I covered up the cage with a blanket. I'm going to leave them on the steps of a shelter or just let them loose. Even though they seem to have accommodated well in the car, it's not healthy for me to be in my car with two rabbits defecating because of the disagreeable smell.

**Any ideas? I'm open to suggestions before they find themselves in a whole new world.**

And please don't say "take them to a shelter," it's not as easy as people may think. Most of the time shelters are full and charge money for taking animals; they have restrictions and want things that sometimes we don't have.

If you haven't been in my shoes, don't say "take them to a shelter." I think I'd be doing them a huge favor by freeing them in the wild; they can't last any less than a wild rabbit. Wild rabbits don't live long. In my opinion they have just as good a chance as any other rabbit.

It boils down to how lucky they are I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would suggest closing your question as a duplicate of our exting question [Can I release my pet rabbit in the wild?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1578) but it sounds like you have done your best due diligence to rehome the rabbits.

I understand your plight, If there are absolutely no options for rehoming them, I think the only responsible choice is euthanasia.

If I knew your general location, I would be happy to try and locate a house rabbit rescue in your area.  It is sometimes possible to have a rescue meet you someplace to take them.